# how to know which keywords matched in elasticsaearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, text-mining, nosql

Say that I query:

```
POST /story/story/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "termVariations":{  
                     "query":"not driving",
                     "type":"boolean",
                     "operator":"AND"
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "termVariations":{  
                     "query":"driving",
                     "type":"boolean",
                     "operator":"AND"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This query returned by one analyzer or another 3 documents. 
How do I tell which should clause was matched? Can Elasticsearch return the matched phrase along with the result?

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) help here ?

Comment: I see that elastic has the explain  API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-explain.html)  but it's a way overkill to what I need and it will make me iterate over each and every result I get because it's per document....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option here would be [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html).
You can name your query and the name of the queries that matched would be provided per document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name.first": {
              "query": "qbox",
              "_name": "first"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name.last": {
              "query": "search",
              "_name": "last"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nice forgot about `named queries`.

Comment: great! :) I wonder what makes highlight so costy vs. this one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @keety! [highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) was exactly what I was looking for!! :-)

Comment: Check my answer , highlight is costly for this kind of task and its an overkill.